# Need help to get the Selenium cssSelector for the following td attribute to extract the title text

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Need help to get the Selenium cssSelector for the following td attribute to extract the title text that is "Nothing here"

```
    <table id="myTable">
  <thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="attr: { title: $root.tooltipText($data) }" title="Nothing here">
            <i class="colNotes fa hasNoNotes fa-comments-o" data-bind="click: function () { $root.noteClicked($data) }, css: $root.notesCssStyling($data)">
            <span class="colNotesText" data-bind="text: NumberOfNotes">0</span>
            </i>
        </td><br/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="attr: { title: $root.tooltipText($data) }" title="Nothing here">
            <i class="colNotes fa hasNoNotes fa-comments-o" data-bind="click: function () { $root.noteClicked($data) }, css: $root.notesCssStyling($data)">
            <span class="colNotesText" data-bind="text: NumberOfNotes">0</span>
            </i>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried the following with no luck

> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myTable tr:nth-child(1)
>   td[data-bind^='attr: { title']")).getAttribute("title");

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Assuming you just want to get the first td in your table, this will work:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myTable td")).getAttribute("title");
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added the entire html starting from the table and with 2 table rows and data/title that I need help extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. This is the final working code to get the title.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#myTable td:nth-child(1)")).getAttribute("title"));
```